# i write DB fetch code in function but it does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I write this **below** function for Fetch fields from DATABASE but it does not work :

```
function Refresh_TBL_post() {
  global $conn;
  #DB Query Comment
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=? ");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_REQUEST['editpostId']);
  #Run Query In DB
  $stmt->execute();
  #Get Count Of Rows    
  #Refrsh $stmt
  $stmt->get_result();
  $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
  return $row;
}
```

And i call this function like this `Refresh_TBL_post();`
but it does not works . How can i fix it ?

Comment: _$stmt = $stmt->get_result()_?

Comment: yes is it wrong ??

Comment: Anything thrown in the error logs, checking for errors? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Look at this [PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: it does not have any errors .

Comment: @bub This isn't PDO. `bind_param` is `mysqli`, `bindParam` is PDO; also look at tags..

Comment: @chris85 what is _this_? Do you mean the code above or the link?

Comment: @bub The database driver being used in the question.

Comment: As shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466530/mysqli-prepared-statement-unable-to-get-result Have you installed the mysqlnd driver?

Comment: what to do guys ??

Comment: **this is not PDO**

Comment: @chris85 how can i fix it ?

Comment: I don't use `mysqli` often but isn't the `get_result` suppose to be assigned to  a variable then fetched? Also you've checked that each of these steps process as expected?

Comment: @chris85 Tank You . I fixed it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I changed function to below :**

```
function Refresh_TBL_post()
    {
            global $conn;
            #DB Query Comment
             $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=? ");
             $stmt->bind_param("s",$_REQUEST['editpostId']);
            #Run Query In DB
             $stmt->execute();
            #Get Count Of Rows  
             #Refrsh $stmt
              $stmt = $stmt->get_result();
         return $stmt;
    }
```

**and use like this**

```
#Refresh
$stmt_Refresh_Tbl_post=Refresh_TBL_post();
$row=$stmt_Refresh_Tbl_post->fetch_assoc();
```

***or like this***

```
 #Refresh
    $row=Refresh_TBL_post()->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: I would put the `fetch` in the function, and just return the `row` as an array.

Comment: Why not, what happens? Don't use the same variable names.

Comment: @chris85 . It can't Fetch Rows

Answer (score 0):

```
#Refrsh $stmt
$stmt->get_result();
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
return $row;
```

is not the same as what you did last.
You should do this:

```
function Refresh_TBL_post() {
  global $conn;
  #DB Query Comment
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=? ");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_REQUEST['editpostId']);
  #Run Query In DB
  $stmt->execute();
  #Get Count Of Rows    
  #Refrsh $stmt
  $res = $stmt->get_result();
  return $res->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Calling with:

```
$row = Refresh_TBL_post();
```

Which should work. You fetch from get_result and not from stmt in your last post.

Comment: Did you remove the fetch_assoc from the function call in     `$row=Refresh_TBL_post()->fetch_assoc();` ? Because this should work... As it is technically the same as below what you said did work. Maybe you can clarify what it is that doesn't work. How do you try to use this code? Do you get any error in the log or does it show you any errors when display_errors is turned on?

Comment: no errors are in my code . yes when i toke out fetch_assoc from my function . it works as well ..