# Looking for an alternative to get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am searching for hours for an alternative to function get_result() in PHP.

THis is the code:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error at line:

```
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Read the documentation: This function is only available with the `mysqlnd` driver.

Comment: @Barmar, this is the error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466530/mysqli-prepared-statement-unable-to-get-result

Comment: If you don't have that driver, you need to use `bind_result()` to bind the result columns to variables, you can't use `fetch_assoc()` with prepared statements.

Comment: @Barmar, I have checked the question you say I am duplicating, but I am not able to make it work on my case.Would you mind to give me an example of bind_result()?

Comment: Change your query to `SELECT encrypted_password FROM ...`. Then do `$stmt->bind_result($encrypted_password); $stmt->fetch();`.

Comment: The best alternative is PDO

Comment: @Barmar, I have changed the query for: $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT encrypted_password,salt FROM users WHERE email = ?");

Comment: @Barmar, and then I have added:  $user = $stmt->bind_result($encrypted_password,$salt);
            $stmt->fetch(); Now I am not getting the error, but the credentials are not passed ok.

Comment: `bind_result()` doesn't return anything useful to assign to `$user`. If you want to return other columns in an associative array, you'll need to add them to the `SELECT` list, and build the array yourself. If you want generic code to do this, follow some of the related links in the duplicate question.